# How to perform multiple table operations in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multi-table

I just want to perform multiple table operations in single query. The query is:

```
    select name,sno , id  as ids ,(select sum(amount) from client_credits 
where user_id = ids) As total  from clients where sno = '4' and total > '0'
```

This query is not working when I am trying  use ** total > 0 **. Is there any other possibility ways? Please help me.

Comment: Can you say what you want and what is your expected output?

Comment: Total would be a number not a string, have you tried without the quotes around the zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total` is an alias. Aliases are not resolved when the `WHERE` clause is reached.

Try: `where sno = 4 having total > 0`

Alternatively, and more efficiently:

```
SELECT `c`.`name`, `c`.`sno`, `c`.`id`, SUM(`ccr`.`amount`) AS `total`
FROM `clients` AS `c`
JOIN `client_credits` AS `ccr` ON `c`.`id`=`ccr`.`user_id`
WHERE `c`.`sno` = 4
GROUP BY `c`.`id`
```

Notice how the `total > 0` part is gone? That's because if there are no rows to join, then nothing will be joined and the rows are removed from the result ;)

Comment: Thank you so much !! ` where sno = 4 having total > 0 ` is working fine